# Vimeo Video Browser While Creating New Page In Drupal

Tags: 7, media, files

I'm new to Drupal, learning it from past few days.

I want to create a vimeo video browser field widget while creating a page content type. Is there any module available which could help me achieve this?

I have installed various modules like vimeo media module, media embed field which enables me to add the vimeo video URL while creating the new page, I want to make an addition to this functionality like a vimeo video browser window to be opened and I could select the video from the same. Any idea as in how I could accomplish the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO :-), we don't have a code writing service here - please write your own code after doing the appropriate research. If you have issues with that code, that's the right time to ask a question here. Question in current from is too broad to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you for your Reply! As I said I'm new to Drupal I was just inquiring bout any available modules for the same? or any idea to implement...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you this module 
https://drupal.org/project/media 
https://drupal.org/project/media_vimeo

I wish it helps you.